# Write a program that gives the longest period of days when the temperature was always above K degrees

Tags: c++

**Multiple Selection**
My code works fine with the Test 1 inputs but with the Test 2 is stops at the first acceptable indexes and does not continue evaluating other elements and if I remove the break I'm getting off results

**Possible Solution**
I would like an assistance making the code to continue evaluating other elements even after finding a favorable element

**Example Input**

```
Test 1
7 30
25
36
29
33
34
36
30

Test 2
10 30
22
36
31
29
25
36
30
36
36
27
```

**Expected Output**

```
Test 1
4 6

Test 2
6 9
```

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MaxN = 102;

void findInd(int T[], int N, int K){
    int start = 0;  //TODO Recursive
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        if (N >= 1 && N <= 100 && K >= -20 && K <= 50){
            if (T[i] > K && T[i+1] > K){
                start = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (start == 0){
        cout << "none";
        return;
    }
    int end = start;  //TODO recursive
    for (int i = N; i >= start; i--) {
        if (N >= 1 && N <= 100 && K >= -20 && K <= 50){
            if (T[i] > K){
                end = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << start << " " << end;

}

int main() {

    int N, K;
    cin >> N >> K;

    int T[MaxN];
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
        cin >> T[i];
    }

    findInd(T, N, K);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question does not specify your problem. Describe your difficulties in more details

Comment: My code works fine with input Test 1 but it doesn't work with the Test 2 because I can't figure out how to make it continue evaluating recursively without messing the whole code

Comment: @Rabter check my comment above

Comment: It is possible to solve your task in O(n) without recursion. See if you can find it.

Comment: Why do you need recursion?

Comment: By the way, using breaks is bad manners. Your functions should have 1 exit point, especially since it is a learning task

Comment: You don't need to check that the input is in the range that the description specifies that the input will be in.

Comment: @MarkRoberts Im not familiar with O(n) can you explain further

Comment: The for-loop in `main()` may run beyond the end of the allocated storage. You need to either check `N` against `MaxN` (lookout for the one-too-few-error) or allocate enough storage.

Comment: First of all, arrays indexes in c++ start with 0 so each time you use a for from 1 to <=N you get out of range. Moreover, in line 11 you also test T[i+1] (btw that logic which i don't understand), that takes you 2 items out of array range

Comment: @acraig5075 if you look at the Test 2 later elements have the longest period but it does not evaluate them because of the break so I would like a better approach

Comment: Your question about O(n): Wikipedia says »In computer science, big O notation is used to classify algorithms according to how their run time or space requirements grow as the input size grows.« Here that means: if you give your algorithm three times as much input it should only have to run three times as long, not 9 times as long.

Comment: @Rabter I dont like breaks also but I didnt have any alternatives

Comment: To fix your program, firstly fix your ranges. Then you should consider doing it int the same loop: if you see an element that is above K, remember it in start_tmp and for every further element that is also above K, increase a counter. Once you get an element less than K, check if you've counted more elements that the last time. if so, start=start_tmp and end=start+count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one loop and no recursion, but you need more bookkeeping.

Consider the following example execution for your second case.

```
 v - where you're looking
 ^ - the start of the current "at least K" range


 v
22 36 31 29 25 36 30 36 36 27
                               max: 0
    v
22 36 31 29 25 36 30 36 36 27
   ^                           max: 1, start: 1, end: 1
    

       v
22 36 31 29 25 36 30 36 36 27
   ^                           max: 2, start: 1, end: 2

          v
22 36 31 29 25 36 30 36 36 27
                                max: 2, start: 1, end: 2

             v       
22 36 31 29 25 36 30 36 36 27
                                max: 2, start: 1, end: 2

                v
22 36 31 29 25 36 30 36 36 27
               ^                max: 2, start: 1, end: 2
                

                   v
22 36 31 29 25 36 30 36 36 27
               ^               max: 2, start: 1, end: 2

                      v
22 36 31 29 25 36 30 36 36 27
               ^               max: 3, start: 5, end: 7

                         v
22 36 31 29 25 36 30 36 36 27
               ^              max: 4, start: 5, end: 8

                            v
22 36 31 29 25 36 30 36 36 27
                              max: 4, start: 5, end: 8
```

Implementation left as an exercise.